# Paraview Elevation command

Tags: python, paraview

I 've been trying to write a python script for paraview that rotates the camera.
it looks like this:

```
from paraview.simple import *
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()
camera=GetActiveCamera()
# get animation scene
animationScene1 = GetAnimationScene()
#camera.Azimuth(45)          
#Render()
camera.Elevation(45)       
Render()
```

So while azimuth rotates the structure 45 degrees and 8 rotations bring it back to the original position, elevation is different.
It only takes 6 rotations and it is like the rotations 3 and 4 are skipped. It also gives a warning
Reseting view up since view plane normal is parallel

Any suggestions are much appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, if you add the command

```
camera.OrthogonalizeViewUp()
```

it prevents the warning and thus the orientation change of the camera